# Symfony 2.3.6 and doctrine-fixtures-bundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, version, bundle, fixture

I'm learning Symfony with a french tutorial.
I need then to install doctrine-fixtures-bundle, but here is the result of my composer.phar update : http://pastebin.com/55k3zKUQ (kind of big to shows it on stackoverflow)

It seems that the latest version of doctrine-fixtures-bundle doesn't support Symfony 2.3.6.
Am I right? How could I install doctrince fixture bundle on my symfony project?

Here's my composer.json : http://pastebin.com/CpccRyid

Comment: Can you add your composer.json to your question? I think your issue comes from `jms/di-extra-bundle` rather than fixture.

Comment: Can you try to replace `"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*"` with `"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem isn't the doctrine fixtures bundle, another package (`jms/di-extra-bundle`) is complaining about the versions.

You should always skip a lot stuff from the composer error, the first thing you should read is:

> jms/di-extra-bundle 1.1.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle 2.1.*

Here you see that the `jms/di-extra-bundle` version 1.1.0 package `symfony/framework-bundle` version 2.1.* required (in other words, it requires symfony 2.1). You have installed symfony 2.3.x.

Then you read further:

> jms/di-extra-bundle 1.1.1 requires symfony/finder 2.1.*

So if we take version 1.1.1, it doesn't require `symfony/framework-bundle` 2.1, but `symfony/finder` 2.1.*. The result is the same: We should install symfony 2.1 and not 2.3.

Then you go to the [package page](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/di-extra-bundle) to see if there is a version which supports symfony 2.3. And yes, for the latest stable version (1.4.0) the list of dependencies looks like:

```
jms/aop-bundle: >=1.0.0,<1.2-dev
jms/metadata: 1.*
symfony/framework-bundle: ~2.1
symfony/process: ~2.1
symfony/finder: ~2.1
```

`~2.1` means at least 2.1.0. It will match each 2.* version, so 2.3 is supported to. So, you just need to replace `1.1.*` in your `composer.json` for the `jms/di-extra-bundle` to `1.4.*` and then update the packages with the `update` command.